# How to implement single indexed array using javascript linkedlist

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like This

```
    var arrays = [
  {
    "value": "$6"
  },
  {
    "value": "$12"
  },
  {
    "value": "$25"
  },
  {
    "value": "$25"
  },
  {
    "value": "$18"
  },
  {
    "value": "$22"
  },
  {
    "value": "$10"
  }
];
```

I need to implement these array to single indexed array like following array.

```
[{
    "value": "$6",
    "Next": {
        "value": "$12",
        "Next": {
            "value": "$25",
            "Next": {
                "value": "$25",
                "Next": {
                    "value": "$28",
                    "Next": {
                        "value": "$22",
                        "Next": {
                            "value": "$10"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

How can i implement second array push to first array like above array using javascript linkedlist.

Comment: Note in both cases you have just a single array. The second just has a single element. And looks like you are wanting a linked-list object which you wouldn't use a `push()` as object's don't have a `push()` method

Answer (score 2):

Convert the array into a linked list using `Array#reduce` method, wherein each iteration construct the `object/node` and pass the `next` reference for next iteration. As we need to traverse the linked list, we need to keep a reference of `root/head` object.

```js
var arrays = [{
    "value": "$6"
  },
  {
    "value": "$12"
  },
  {
    "value": "$25"
  },
  {
    "value": "$25"
  },
  {
    "value": "$18"
  },
  {
    "value": "$22"
  },
  {
    "value": "$10"
  }
];
var root = {};
arrays.reduce((acc, { value }) => {
  acc.next = { value };
  return acc.next;
}, root);
var result = [root.next];
console.log(result);
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

It will iterate the array in reverse direction and maintaining the previous value and appending it into the current one and return the output.

Try this

```
function parseData(input){
  var output = [];
  var len = input.length;
  var previous = {};
  for(var i =len-1 ; i >= 0; i--){
    var temp = {};
    temp["value"] = input[i].value;
    if(i !== len){
       temp["Next"] = previous;
    }
    previous = temp;
  }
  output.push(previous);
  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let result=[];
for(let i=0; i<arrays.length; i++){ 
   result.push(
      {"value":arrays[i]["value"], "next":arrays[i+1]}
)}
```